# How can I use python to get my lat,lon in OSM?

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I have try geocode to get my lat and lon , but not current

it is get by my ip and conver to lat,lon

Can help me osm(openstreetmap) api can get my current lat and lon?

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

and

```
freegeoip = "http://freegeoip.net/json"
geo_r = requests.get(freegeoip)
geo_json = geo_r.json()

user_postition = [geo_json["latitude"], geo_json["longitude"]]

print(user_postition)
```

Comment: It is not clear which of the two do you need help with. As for "freegeoip", can you test on a browser first? From where I am, somehow that URL is unreachable, and need to use some alternative services, like `https://freegeoip.lwan.ws/`, in which case it works.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap doesn't offer a geolocation API. However you can find various geolocation services and databases on the Internet. Some of them are mentioned here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/ip-geocoding-data-sources-and-or-apis